# truecaller web api not returning auth token

Tags: php, api, asp.net-web-api, auth-token, callbackurl

I am using true caller apis to fetch user data from the true caller database.

As per [TrueCaller's Github documentation](https://github.com/truecaller/web-login),I have used the below code to do the authentication

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "appKey: Js9t3518a9eb2b6804160957f7b438dcc01ac" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
 "phoneNumber": 46760369715
}' "https://api4.truecaller.com/v1/apps/requests"
```

Issue is Im not getting the auth Token as per their documentation.They have mentioned that the auth token will be sent to the call back url of the app.I have put a log in that callback url.But as soon as i hit the above curl,I am not getting the auth token.

Has some one used the above API? What am i doing wrong or is there anything else i should do to get the auth token to the callback url?

Comment: Same issue i am facing. Please suggest the solution if any.

Comment: I'm also facing issue, I'm getting the requestID but How can I get the access token?



curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "appKey: PJI4sf2259656c594461795ccc05c1924a544" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
  "phoneNumber": 8801975585960
}' "https://api4.truecaller.com/v1/apps/requests"

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: I think its problem from their end, however, there is better and easier way to sync names for contacts